# iframes and links in multiple webpages

Tags: html, iframe, href

I have a webpage A.html. There are 3 other web pages a1.html a2.html a3.html. a1, a2 and a3 should always open in the iframe inside A.html.

Now there is another webpage B.html which has links to A, a1, a2 and a3. Link for A is not a problem, but how do i put links in B for a1 a2 and a3 so that they open in the iframe inside A?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want a structure similar to this:

```
B-----------------------
  A---------------------
     a1-----------------
     a2-----------------
     a3-----------------
```

Means that `B` has links to `A` and `A` has links to `a1`, `a2` and `a3`.

If this is the scenario, then just link `a1`, `a2` and `a3` to `A.html`. After than link `A.html` to the `iframe` in `B.html`.

Code could be something like:

**B.html**

```
<iframe src="A.html"></iframe>
```

**A.html**

```
<iframe src="a1.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="a2.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="a3.html"></iframe>
```

And then you could separately have `a1`, `a2` and `a3` html files that would have some stuff.

***You don't have to put links for `a1`, `a2` and `a3` in `B.html` because you have loaded the file `A.html` which already has links to those files.***

---

This is the structure you will get by using proper width and heights:

[image]

If this is not your scenario, then explain a bit more in your question.

---

If I understand you correctly, you want the links on `B.html` to open `a1`, `a2` and `a3`
in `A.html`. So for instance, I clicked on `a1` which shall open `a1` inside `A.html`.

This can not be done just by plain html because your links are on a separate page. So, somehow you need to tell the other page (in your case `A.html`) to open `default`, `a1`... and so on.

You can do this using plain `javascript`. In `B.html` in your links, you need to send the information to `A.html` about what file to open in the `iframe`:

```
<a href="A.html">A</a>
<a href="A.html#a1">a1</a>
<a href="A.html#a2">a2</a>
<a href="A.html#a3">a3</a>
```

The `#a1`, `#a2`... will tell your `A.html` page to open the requested page in its iframe.

Now you need to read these hash values on `A.html`. You can do this when body triggers `onload` event.

```
<body onload="changeSrc()">
<!-- Load the default page in the iframe, for instance a1.html -->
<iframe id="abc" src="a1.html"></iframe>
<script>
    function changeSrc() {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        var frame = document.getElementById("abc");

        if(hash == "#a1") {
            frame.src = "a1.html";
        }
        else if(hash == "#a2") {
            frame.src = "a2.html";
        }
        else if(hash == "#a3") {
            frame.src = "a3.html";
        }
        else {
            // default
            frame.src = "a1.html";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

This will do the task.

So, by using `window.location.hash` you are actually getting the value that you have passed in the `url`, say `#a1`, `#a2`,... And by checking which page was requested in the `if/else` condition, you are setting the source of the frame to that particular page.

Hope this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: no, there is only one iframe in A. a1, a2 and a3 must open independently(and not at the same time).And there is no iframe in B.

Comment: i have added an image. take a look.

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your image. Check if I get you correctly this time.